# Integral of $x_ix_j$ over surface of arbitrary sphere

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

This is a multiple-choice question from an old exam, meaning it should be answerable in minutes without writing out anything. I'm afraid therefore that I'm missing some crucial insight/intuition about integrals.

Let $M$ be the surface of the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\omega_M=\int_M1d\sigma$. Which is true?

1. $\int_Mx_ix_jd\sigma = 0, 1\le i, j\le n$
2. $\int_Mx_ix_jd\sigma = \frac 1 {n^2}\omega_M, 1\le i, j\le n$
3. $\int_Mx_ix_jd\sigma = 0, 1\le i\ne j\le n$
4. $\int_Mx_i^2d\sigma=\frac 1 {n^2}\omega_M, 1\le i\le n$

I could disprove options 1. and 2. in my head and in fact 3. and 4. hold in $\mathbb R^2$ for the Lebesgue measure, i.e., $\sigma=\lambda$.

Is there some semi-obvious reason why 3. or 4. is correct?

Comment: While integration over the surface of the unit sphere you have to define the system of coordinates in $\mathbb R^n$ and define $\vec{r}$ and its coordinates {$x_i$} in the chosen system. You may rotate the system of coordinates (and $x_i$ will transform), but the result of integration should not depend of these rotations - you don't have a selected directions in $\mathbb R^n$ (defined,for instance, by a fixed vector $\vec{a}$). So, the result of integration can be expressed by means of the rotation  invariant object which, in you case, can only be $\delta_{ij}$ (Kronecker symbol).

Comment: $\int_Mx_ix_jd\sigma =C(n)\delta_{ij}$ ($=1$ if $i=j$, and zero otherwise). $C(n)$ can be easily found - just sum up both sides over $i=j$: $\int_M\sum_{i=1}^n{x}_ix_id\sigma =\int_Md\sigma$    $(\sum_{i=1}^n{x}_ix_i=1) =C(n)\sum_i\delta_{ii}=nC(n)=\omega_M$ $\Rightarrow$ $C(n)=\frac{1}{n}$